# Effect of TARGET property inside tsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2020

Below is the **tsconfig.json** of my project.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "typeRoots": [
            "src/types",
            "node_modules/@types",
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

My  **Typescript** version is  "typescript": "^3.9.5"
and **Node** version us ts-node": "^8.10.2".

I just want to confirm if i change my `target` inside `tsconfig.json` file from `"target": "es6" to` "target": "es2020"`.How will it effect my current project or i am good.

Comment: I doubt that node 8.10 does support ES2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is a superset of ES6, so you’re essentially writing TS code using ES6 version of JavaScript. However, when compiled, the resulting JS code can be in ES5 or earlier. You need to define which version of JS the compiler should transpile into. This can be set using target option